Meaning of コピー付けて in this sentence?

The character is talking about a book he wrote and says this after mentioning the book was fairly popular. In the first part he mentions all kind of Sensei introduced the book and then he adds this
"コピー" mean "copy" but also apparently slogan  for advertising? I'm not quite sure what to make of it. "I even received a copy (of my own book)"?

Since this concerns a book, I think it's likely that コピー does not refer to an advertising slogan, per se, but rather to what speakers of American English commonly refer to as a blurb – that is, a short bit of prose praising the book, to be used as advertising on the dust jacket, back cover, or obi.
Also, I think you may be misinterpreting the first part of the sentence. I'd take it to mean not that 色んな偉いセンセー introduced the book, but that the speaker was introduced to 色んな偉いセンセー .
A somewhat loose translation might be something like

I was introduced to all sorts of distinguished [writers/scholars/doctors]*, who were kind enough to write blurbs for me

I'm just guessing about this next part, but from what you've written, and also the use of けど, it sounds like this sentence may have been included to soften what might otherwise have sounded like bragging. On the other hand, depending on the story and what the character is like, I guess it could itself be a form of "humblebrag." (As in, "My book was quite popular, although I can't take full credit for that since so many distinguished people said such nice things about it.") And either way, the use of the 〜たり…〜たり form implies there were other, unspecified factors that also contributed to the book's popularity.

*"Writers" or "authors" seems like the likeliest translation for センセー here, but it's hard to be sure without more context.

Yes it seem to be short for キャッチコピー "advertising slogan", which is not strange as what other famous/influential authors (偉いセンセー) do for him.
P.S.

４ 広告の文章。広告の文案。「キャッチ—」「—ライター」 ( https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%94%E3%83%BC )

I have learned that it is actually not an abbreviation...

The word "copy" is also used in English in this sense: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_(publishing)
